# A list of Map<>, moving a specifc map object to first index

Tags: java

I am tying to move a specific item to index 0 from a list of Map<String, Object>

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> unique = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String, Object> m1 = new HashMap<>();
    m1.put("name", "NUMBER ONE");
    m1.put("isCorrect", false);

    Map<String, Object> m2 = new HashMap<>();
    m2.put("name", "MOVE THIS ONE TO i0");
    m2.put("isCorrect", true);

    Map<String, Object> m3 = new HashMap<>();
    m3.put("name", "NUMBER TWO");
    m3.put("isCorrect", false);

    unique.add(m1);
    unique.add(m2);
    unique.add(m3);

    System.out.println(unique);

    for (int i = 0; i < unique.size(); i++) {
        if ((boolean) unique.get(i).get("isCorrect")) {
            unique.remove(i);
            unique.add(0, unique.get(i));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(unique);
```

It prints this.

```
[{name=NUMBER ONE, isCorrect=false}, {name=MOVE THIS ONE TO i0, isCorrect=true}, {name=NUMBER TWO JONES, isCorrect=false}]
[{name=NUMBER TWO, isCorrect=false}, {name=NUMBER ONE, isCorrect=false}, {name=NUMBER TWO, isCorrect=false}]
```

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: `unique.remove(i)` means it's gone. You then call `unique.get(i)` but that gets the item _after_, because you _removed_ the item. Call `unique.get(i)` first, save it in a variable.

Comment: by *some coincidence*, `remove(int)` returns the element that was removed... so `var map = unique.remove(i); unique.add(0, map);` - these can even be joined as `unique.add(0, unique.remove(i))` (I probably would not do the last since the first is easier to understand and debug)

Comment: Just swap: `int ixTarget = -1;for (int i = 0; i < unique.size(); i++) {if ((boolean) unique.get(i).get("isCorrect")) {ixTarget = i;break;}}if (ixTarget > 0) {Collections.swap(unique, 0, ixTarget);}`

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to assume that there will be no more than one Map with isCorrect set to true, your code is fine.  (But in that case, I would have expected you to `break` out of the loop as soon as you performed the move.)

If there might be more than one, a for-loop is not a good choice for this.  When you call `unique.remove(i)`, you are removing the Map at that index.  Once you do that, the *next Map in the List* resides at that index.  But then the for-loop increments `i`, so you are effectively *skipping* the Map that follows the one you removed.

I would make a separate collection of all correct elements, and add it after the loop:

```
Collection<Map<String, Object>> correct = new ArrayList<>();

Iterator<Map<String, Object>> i = unique.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    Map<String, Object> m = i.next();
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(m.get("isCorrect"))) {
        correct.add(m);
        i.remove();
    }
}

unique.addAll(0, correct);
```

`Boolean.TRUE.equals(m.get("isCorrect"))` will work, without ever causing an exception, for any value that might be in the Map, including the case where no ‘isCorrect’ value is in the Map at all.

Using the List’s Iterator to traverse and remove elements guarantees that no Map will be missed.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
On a side note, I personally would not modify the array while iterating over it, some data structures implementations are not prepared for that.

Other have said correctly the your are removing the item first, which is wrong.

---

---

But for the solutions, I would give you 2.

For one, you could sort the array, using the sort criteria as the value from the map, as a custom comparator.
This answer shows it with an integers array: [How to sort an array of ints using a custom comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699141/how-to-sort-an-array-of-ints-using-a-custom-comparator). And this one with a java 8 stream which I like more: [How to define custom sorted comparator in java 8 Stream to compare on the key and the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612318/how-to-define-custom-sorted-comparator-in-java-8-stream-to-compare-on-the-key-an).

For a java stream of `Map<String, Object>`

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
  List<Map<String, Object>> unique = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String, Object> m1 = new HashMap<>();
    m1.put("name", "NUMBER ONE");
    m1.put("isCorrect", false);

    Map<String, Object> m2 = new HashMap<>();
    m2.put("name", "MOVE THIS ONE TO i0");
    m2.put("isCorrect", true);

    Map<String, Object> m3 = new HashMap<>();
    m3.put("name", "NUMBER TWO");
    m3.put("isCorrect", false);

    unique.add(m1);
    unique.add(m2);
    unique.add(m3);

    System.out.println(unique);
    
    final var size = unique.size();

    unique = unique.stream().sorted(new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {
    public int compare(Map<String, Object> m1, Map<String, Object> m2) {
        return ((Boolean)m1.getOrDefault("isCorrect", false)) ? -1 : (((Boolean)m2.getOrDefault("isCorrect", false)) ? 1 : 0);
    }
}).collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(size)));
    System.out.println(unique);
    
    
    }
}
```

Note that:

- Sorting an array can be overkill, compares too much stuff
- Can be used for trivial, non critical code that will run

The ideal thing would be finding the one you want, then moving it to the first position:

```
    System.out.println(unique);
    
    var foundIndex = -1;
    // TODO: Is it possible not to find it ? will there only be one of it ?
    
    for (int i = 0; i < unique.size(); i++) {
        if ((boolean) unique.get(i).get("isCorrect")) {
            foundIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    unique.add(0, unique.get(foundIndex));
    unique.remove(foundIndex+1);
    
    
    System.out.println(unique);
```

[image: Test run]

Things to think:

- Could there be more than one match ?
- Could the value not exist ?
- `ArrayList is not performant to insert at the head`, if this is not a critical code, its ok. But removing is O(1), things to consider: https://www.baeldung.com/java-collections-complexity.

Some code adjusments would need to be made.